# Why is MMIO space mapped to /dev/mem as a single PTE so there is no struct page?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

On Linux, MMIO space is mapped (for example via /dev/mem, by calling `remap_pfn_range()`) as a single PTE so there is no struct page.

Why Linux does not create a lot of PTE with struct page?

Comment: Fewer abbreviations (and I do know "memory-mapped I/O" and "page table entry" but it makes the question hard to read).  What "struct page" is is not clear at all.  Do you mean there is no memory page containing structs?  Or no `struct` type named `page`?  Or no structure representing a memory page?  Or there is a `struct page` type but it is not used for MMIO?

Comment: @Ben Voigt "there is no struct page" - I mean that there are not PTEs (Page Table Entries) for each page of memory, but there is only a single PTE for /dev/mem.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to answer this to the best of my ability. It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking when you ask, `Why Linux does not create a lot of PTE with struct page?`. But, I think your main question is, "why does MMIO not use `struct page`?" But you also mention, `as a single PTE so there is no struct page`. Some clarification:

- There would only be a single PTE if MMIO region is less than or equal to the size of a page. If the MMIO region is larger than a page, there would be more than a single PTE.
- There is a `struct page`, it is just "not used" when MMIO happens.

**From my understanding, the answer is:**

There is one and only one `struct page` for every page in physical memory. The `struct page` that maps to a page in memory never changes (although the underlying data in memory can change). The `struct page` stores usage information about a physical page in memory. And also note, that a **single** `struct page` exists for **each** physical page in memory. Generally, references to these `struct page` are kept in a well-known location, typically `mem_map`.

Also, keep in mind that a Linux page table entry (PTE) also stores usage information about a page. The Linux PTE is roughly kept in-sync with any hardware Memory Management Unit's "PTE" for a given page.

If physical memory **addresses** are mapped to a device (i.e. MMIO), there are no `struct page`s for the device's memory. The `struct page`s for the physical memory at those physical addresses still exist, BUT they aren't used like they normally are, since that physical memory is now unused (but the physical **addresses** are being used to point to memory that is not in physical memory anymore, but in the device's memory).

Remember, there exists one `struct page` for every page in physical memory in a well-known location: a pre-allocated array named `mem_map`.

Therefore, PTEs are sufficient to keep track of the state of a device's memory. The `struct page` structure is specifically for memory in the system's physical memory. But page table entries can be used to keep track of the state any memory, not just physical memory.

Comment: Thank you very much! I.e. for `/dev/mem` (MMIO) there aren't any `struct page`s, and there are many PTEs, isn't it? But how can I create `struct page`s for `/dev/mem` MMIO, can I do this by using `ioremap_wc(phys_addr, size)`, or by using `vm_insert_page(wma, addr, page)`?

Comment: I'm not surei understand what you mean, but `/dev/mem` is not MMIO. `/dev/mem` gives access to the entire physical address space. This means that `struct page`s already exist for all the physical memory in the system. There aren't any `struct page` for device memory (MMIO). You just directly access the device memory using physical memory **addresses*

Comment: But no, you do not use `ioremap` or `vm_insert_page` to create `struct page`s. `ioremap` just maps device I/O to virtual memory. `vm_insert_page` is for already-created `struct page`. Is there a reason why you want to create `struct page`s for device I/O memory? You shouldn't have a need to do that

Comment: Developers from nVidia said, that: " `cudaHostRegister(virt_ptr, size, 0)` is not ready to handle virtual addresses without a corresponding struct page". And I can't map device memory to the virtual user-space memory, and then remap it to the GPU-memory (UVA), to use it from GPU. One of variants for solve this problem, that: "The problem seems to originate from the nvidia driver and the flags and/or structure associations it expects to be present on the virtual memory area passed to `cudaHostRegister`.However, the driver comes as a binary blob with no source code available..."

Comment: continuation: "... In order to overcome this problem, the netmap kernel module, and more specifically the code that implements the `mmap(3)` functionality, was modified. The patch simply changes the routines used to export the allocated pages to userspace. Apparently, the problem here is the use of `remap_pfn_range` which produces raw PFN (Page Frame Number) mappings and the pages do not have a struct page associated with them. Using `vm_insert_page` for every page instead works."

Comment: Are you trying to map another device's memory to your GPU's memory by using MMIO as an intermediary?

Comment: Yes. With `vm_insert_page()` it works, with `remap_pfn_range()` it doesn't.

Comment: Do you know why is it happening?